# No subject alternative DNS name matching api.imgur.com found. when using Scribe to access api.imgur.com

Tags: java, ssl, scribe, imgur

I am having difficulty trying to get Scribe to interface with Imgur. I keep getting

java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching api.imgur.com found.

From what I can gather from [general solutions for these types of issues](http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1095/) is that the common name on the certificate doesn't match the server name, but I inspected the cert at https://api.imgur.com/oauth/request_token and turned up nothing that even suggests this (api.imgur.com == api.imgur.com, seriously, how does this not match). Anyway, the here is the code that I am using.

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder().debug().provider(ImgUrApi.class)
  .provider(ImgUrApi.class)
  .apiKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
  .apiSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)
  .build();

Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken(); //Fails here
```

And here is the output from the debug

```
obtaining request token from https://api.imgur.com/oauth/request_token
setting oauth_callback to oob
generating signature...
base string is: POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.imgur.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%<my-imgur-key>%26oauth_nonce%3D190893231%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1350152724%26oauth_version%3D1.0
signature is: WGRVhKKWqiFiD939LI3eOHHKAJg=
appended additional OAuth parameters: { oauth_callback -> oob , oauth_signature -> WGRVhKKWqiFiD939LI3eOHHKAJg= , oauth_version -> 1.0 , oauth_nonce -> 190893231 , oauth_signature_method -> HMAC-SHA1 , oauth_consumer_key -> <my-imgur-key> , oauth_timestamp -> 1350152724 }
using Http Header signature
sending request...
```

Not sure what else I can do to fix the issue since nothing looks broken. I imagine that I am missing something blatantly obvious.

Comment: On a whim I tried the same code with twitter and it worked!. I think the problem is that the jar file in the download section was missing the imgur api class. I thought I could just add it in myself. This might be my problem. I am going to just download the Scribe source and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the problem is the class not being in the package, if so it should fail before even trying to get the request token with a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Seems like you're indeed having a certificate problem, you'll need to dig more but for now I guess this can help:

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.net.ssl/trustall.html

Note that using this on production presents a security problem, it's just to prove the point and reduce the problem space.

Comment: Just an update. I read up on [Apache's HTTPComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) to roll my own logic to connect to the Imgur API, and I am still getting the same issue. I am not sure what the answer will be. The weirdest part is that the certificate looks fine when I visit the URI through a web browser.

Comment: I reached out to the Imgur and they stated that they use [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), and it appears that there is still some discussion for HTTPComponents concerning this at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1119. I will try to update with a formal answer later.